# Replacing the IONIC's www folder makes no difference

Tags: ionic-framework

It's been a while since I developed in ionic ( 1 yr ).  I think things have changed.

I used to be able to create a new blank template ionic project at a local folder on the mac and then replace its placeholder www folder with another project's www folder. This used to work.

Now, replacing the www folder in that ionic blank project makes no difference when I run any of these commands
`ionic serve` 
`cordova build ios` 
`cordova emulate ios`

I keep seeing the "`The world is your oyster`" message.

In fact, when I even renamed the local folder that was holding the entire ionic project, the `cordova build ios` still has worked without any complaints.

Clearly, the code is running somewhere else.

I also notice this at the terminal prompt:
`➜  vb git:(master)`

Here the git:(master) thing is new to me. Could this be the culprit?

If so, how can I disassociate the github aspect so I can work on the local and quickly test the changes I will be making in the local www as easy as going `cordova build ios`?

Comment: i don't know which version you are using, but last time i tried ionic 2, there was a compilation process to do, from the typescript files to a minified core file, the latter being actually used instead of the separate files

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to a fellow at the ionic forums. will post it as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when I created the blank project, I used the defaults which now outputs an ionic 2 baby.

I did the following 2 changes to solve my problem.

create my app for version 1 by appending `--type=ionic1` as follows:

`ionic cordova start myapp -blank --type=ionic1`

I also prefixed allmy  `cordova` commands with `ionic` name space.

Now I can replace the www all day long and my `ionic cordova build ios` & `ionic cordova emulate ios` will comply.

hope it will help someone.